# Unique event namespacing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say you have a plugin that attaches a scroll event to the window and compares the scroll position to the element's(this) offset. Naturally, you would want a way to unbind that event when it's not needed.

I would like to do something similar to:

```
unbind("scroll.uniqueNamespace")
```

But, if you use the plugin on more than one element, it will unbind all the scroll events with "scroll.uniqueNamespace", when I need it to remove only for one element.

I'm considering storing an array/object of elements and namespace every element uniquely, but that just seems messy.

Comment: instead of binding a ton of events, why not bind one event and then only check for stuff in your array of active elements in the listener to that event

Comment: @zachallia, I like that idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unbind a specific listener, jQuery accepts a second parameter in `.unbind`

```
.unbind( eventType [, handler(eventObject) ] )
```

So, you can store the listener function in your array of elements, and when you unbind, pass that listener to the unbind method. Something like:

```
unbind("scroll.uniqueNamespace", els[el].listener)
```

Also, repeating my comment on your question, but you could also add only one listener and do the check for only your active elements inside that listener.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/